# EISDIR error when using fs writeFile, but the folder does exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I use request to get a page which has a bunch of anchor tags (100) in a table which I parse through using cheerio.

I get the value of the href property for each anchor tag and request each page.

I then parse each page using cheerio. So, the text in the h1 tag in the new page becomes my file name.

So when I want to write some content to this particular file name using fs write,  I get

{ Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/samples/'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/samples/' }

However, some of the files are created but the vast majority are not. The samples folder does exist. In addition to this error I am also getting a cheerio parse error

/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/node_modules/cheerio/lib/parse.js:69
    var oldParent = node.parent || node.root,
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
    at Function.exports.update (/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/node_modules/cheerio/lib/parse.js:69:25)
    at module.exports (/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/node_modules/cheerio/lib/parse.js:19:11)
    at Function.exports.load (/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/node_modules/cheerio/lib/static.js:27:14)
    at Request._callback (/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/scrape.js:19:24)
    at self.callback (/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/node_modules/request/request.js:884:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)

This is my code

```
 request(seed, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);

       $('td:first-child a').each(function(i, element){

          var fullUrl = seed + element.attribs.href.substring(1);
          request(fullUrl, function(error, response, body) {

              var $$ = cheerio.load(body);

              var title = $$('h1[property="dc:title"]').text();

              fs.writeFile('/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/samples/' + title, 'some random text', function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                      return console.log(err)
                  }
              });

          });
      });
   }
 });
```

Edit: I added some checks based on robert's suggestions. Now I don't get the EISDIR error, however many of the files which do have valid titles are still not getting created. The parse issue still persists.

```
request(seed, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);

       $('td:first-child a').each(function(i, element){

          var fullUrl = seed + element.attribs.href.substring(1);
          request(fullUrl, function(error, response, body) {

              if(body === undefined || body === '' || body === null) {
                console.log('wonky');
                console.log(element.attribs.href.substring(1));// Every execution of the program prints something different
              }
              var $$ = cheerio.load(body);

              var title = $$('h1[property="dc:title"]').text();

              if(title !== '' && title !== undefined && title !== null) {
             fs.writeFile('/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/samples/' + title, 'some random text', function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                      return console.log(err)
                  }
              });
             }
          });
      });
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not checking if `title` actually contains a proper filename.

My guess is that it's empty, which means that you're trying to `writeFile` to the directory itself, which is what the error states as well: *"illegal operation on a directory"*.

Comment: hmm now i added a check for the title making sure it isn't undefined before doing the writeFile. One thing that I didn't mention in my post was that after those EISDIR errors I also got a parse error from cheerio. So I added a check to see if the body being loaded into $$ was undefined or not and lo and behold sometimes it was undefined. I then printed out the element.attribs.href.substring(1) to find the culprit, but then for each execution of the program, I got different culprits! I think the issue has something to do with some asynchronous wonky thing happening.

Comment: It's not strange that the value changes, because you're logging it _inside_ the handler of an async function. You're basically starting 100 concurrent HTTP requests, and you can't make assumptions in which order they complete. The stack trace isn't very clear, but you should look for locations in your own code (as opposed to locations in libraries) that appear in it. They may provide a clue why you get the error (although for the nested `request` call, you're still calling `cheerio.load()` while the body may be "wonky"). Also, check `error` in the nested `request` call.

Comment: Hi! Checking the error and the response.statusCode for the inner request gave me some insight as to what the problem was. It turns out that the website I was scraping was sending a response with status code of 503. This could be because I am making multiple requests with no delay between them. In order to resolve this, what would you suggest? Keep retrying if 503 or introduce a delay between each request?

Comment: @DhruvPrakash take a look at [`async.queue()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue), which you can use the limit the concurrent amount of requests. The idea would be that inside the `.each()` loop, you'd push the URL's into the queue, and you'd have a queue handler that would perform the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect you should use this

you should write the file name and its format in your path

```
fs.writeFile('/Users/dhruvprakash/Desktop/Projects/simple-node-scraper/samples/file.name + format' + title, 'some random text', function (err) {
```